# How to screencast to a video file using java?

Tags: java

In some situations (automated testing) I need to screencast my display(s) to **video file(s)**, but currently i can only save a series of PNG files using Robot and ImageIO classes, I know there are other third party programs to convert this set of image files into a video file but I want to make it in my code without a need to third party applications, so how to convert from a series of PNG files into a video file in any format ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve: video streaming or save as video file or both?

Comment: Your question does appear to match your title.

Answer (score 1):

I would just get `FFmpeg` and use that to convert your images to video. You can make syscalls in Java if what you mean by "third party application" is "I don't want to do it manually" as `FFmpeg` supports command-line.

For example, maybe something like

```
String[] cmds = {"path/to/ffmpeg", args ... }
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

There are many tutorials available on how to use ffmpeg to convert a sequence of images to a video file.

Comment: I know [this](http://www.michw.com/2012/01/ffmpeg/) but I still need to do it in my code.